# How to create C API to C++ Function

Tags: c++, c, c++14

I am learning how to generate an array of random numbers in C++. I am using a std::vector and std::generate (I'm trying to use modern idiomatic C++ - not sure how well I'm doing).

What I would like to do is to expose this function to plain old C code. How can make this function available from C?

Code below. Thanks!

```
void RandomArray(std::vector<double> &data)
{
    std::random_device rd{};
    auto mtgen = std::mt19937{ rd() };
    auto ud = std::uniform_int_distribution<>{ 1, 6 };
    auto gen = [&ud, &mtgen](){ return ud(mtgen); };

    std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), gen);
}
```

Comment: C doesn't have `vector<double>`. How would the  C code call it?

Comment: You'll need an interface function which converts back and forth the `std::vector`.

Comment: Containers passed by reference don't make idiomatic C++. Use iterators. If you templatise the function then it's very easy to create a C compatible wrapper that doesn't require any massive conversion.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `extern "C"` statement to make the function linkable to `C` code.

But working from your `C++` version to the `C` version is harder I think, it would go something like this:

```
void RandomArray(std::vector<double> &data)
{
    std::random_device rd{};
    auto mtgen = std::mt19937{ rd() };
    auto ud = std::uniform_int_distribution<>{ 1, 6 };
    auto gen = [&ud, &mtgen](){ return ud(mtgen); };

    std::generate(data.begin(), data.end(), gen);
}

extern "C" void RandomArray(double* data, size_t size)
{
    std::vector<double> v(size);
    RandomArray(v);
    std::copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), data); // need to copy out
}
```

Personally I would go the other way and make the `C` version the main algorithm and get the `C++` version to call that:

```
extern "C" void RandomArray(double* data, size_t size)
{
    std::random_device rd{};
    auto mtgen = std::mt19937{ rd() };
    auto ud = std::uniform_int_distribution<>{ 1, 6 };
    auto gen = [&ud, &mtgen](){ return ud(mtgen); };

    std::generate(data, data + size, gen);
}

void RandomArray(std::vector<double>& data)
{
    RandomArray(data.data(), data.size());
}
```

Also it would be a lot faster not to initialize the random generator each time you call the function. One way to do that is making the random generator `static`. If you need thread safety you could also make it `thread_local`:

```
extern "C" void RandomArray(double* data, size_t size)
{
    thread_local static auto mtgen = std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()};
    auto ud = std::uniform_int_distribution<>{ 1, 6 };

    std::generate(data, data + size, [&ud](){ return ud(mtgen); });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While C++ has standard support to call C functions, the reverse is not true.  The only way to call a C++ function from C code is to make it C-compatible and use the C++ facilities to call it as a C function  (only the function internal body code is C++ code), and compile it with a C++ compiler, to produce a C++ object code that has a C entry point

## mod.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
void my_function(const char *sample_parameter1, const int sample_parameter2);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

## mod.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mod.h"

void my_function(const char *sample_parameter1, const int sample_parameter2)
{
    std::cout << sample_parameter1
              << ", "
              << sample_parameter2
              << std::endl;
}
```

And then

## main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mod.h"
int main()
{
    my_function("Sample literal 1", 37);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

To compile this, you need the following sequence:

```
$ c++ -o mod.o -c mod.cc
$ cc -o main.o -c main.c
$ c++ main.o mod.cc
$ a.out
```

(You need to invoque c++ to make the link phase, as it needs to include the standard c++ modules required at link time)

As far as you have included a c++ module, the whole project must be considered a c++ project and not C, because you'll need the C++ runtime modules to initialize properly all the global c++ objects you declare in your c++ modules and to include the c++ libraries you may use.  You'll only compile with the `cc` C compiler only the modules that are pure C (and you have to use the C++ rules to distinguish them as C code)

The c++ compiler uses a different naming procedure for identifiers and all the C identifiers must be marked `extern "C"` (that's the reason of the `mod.h` file)  If you don't follow that you'll lead to a `unknown function 'my_function'` linker message because C++ names include information about the parameter list types used in them, to allow for overloaded function names.